# Como saber qual a página atual dos meus dados vindos da API?

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Fiz a integração de uma *API*, mas ela não tem *endpoint* de "page" para saber qual é a página atual que está.

Com base nisso, gostaria de uma ajuda para criar algo para descobrir a página atual que o usuário está para fazer uma paginação utilizando **redux-saga**. Atualmente os *payloads* que recebo da *API* são um **token**, **licitacoesPorPagina = 6** (quantos dados que serão exibidos na página) e uma palavra chave que é digitada pelo usuário, após isso a requisição é feita para a *API* e retorna os dados em uma tabela.

A documentação da *API* é esta: [API de Licitações](https://alertalicitacao.com.br/!api)

Minhas **actions**:

```
export const getSearchOpportunitiesData = (data) => ({
  type: GET_SEARCH_OPPORTUNITIES,
  payload: data,
})

export const getSearchOpportunitiesFailed = (error) => ({
  type: GET_SEARCH_OPPORTUNITIES_FAILED,
  payload: error,
})

export const getSearchOpportunitiesSucceeded = data => ({
  type: GET_SEARCH_OPPORTUNITIES_SUCCESS,
  payload: { data },
})
```

Meu **reducer**:

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  itens: [],
  currentPage: 0,
  paginationMode: true,
}

export const SearchOpportunities = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log('action: ', action)

  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_SEARCH_OPPORTUNITIES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [...state.data, action.payload.data],
      }
    case GET_ID_LICITACAO_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        itens: [...state.itens, action.payload.data.itens]
      }
    case GET_SEARCH_OPPORTUNITIES_FAILED:
    case GET_ID_LICITACAO_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload.data,
      }
    default: 
      return state
  }
}
```

Minha **saga**:

```
function* getSearchOpportunities({ currentPage, keyword }) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(searchOpportunities, keyword, currentPage);
    console.log('response: ', response)
    yield put(getSearchOpportunitiesSucceeded(response))
  } catch(error) {
    yield put(getSearchOpportunitiesFailed(error))
  }
}

function* watchGetSearchOpportunities() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_SEARCH_OPPORTUNITIES, getSearchOpportunities)
  yield takeLatest(GET_ID_LICITACAO, getSingleIdLicitacao)
}

function* searchOpportunitiesSagas() {
  yield all([fork(watchGetSearchOpportunities)]);
}

export default searchOpportunitiesSagas;
```

Meu **index.js** onde é feito o meu dispatch:

```
const detectKeyPress = (e) => {
        const { key } = e;

        if (key === 'Enter') {
            try {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_SEARCH_OPPORTUNITIES,
                    keyword: searchedWord,
                    currentPage: currentPage,
                });
            } catch (error) {
                dispatch(getSearchOpportunitiesFailed(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

Tentei fazer dessa forma, mas sem sucesso até o momento. Agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda ;)

Comment: A `API`, retorna o total da paginas e por padrão a primeira página quando não é informado, depois disso é só calcular pelo retorno enviado.

Comment: Eu vi isso há algum tempo atrás, só que tem um problema no meu state que ele está me retornando os dados da API em um array de objetos, e eu estou renderizando eles dessa forma: 

[link](https://i.imgur.com/2c0SDDF.png)

Ou seja, ele só está pegando o primeiro índice do arrary. Como faço para pegar o restante dos índices conforme digito em "próxima página"?